# How to create Heat Map without creating so many arrays for Z value Plotly

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly

I have a very large dataset and creating a heatmap with the z value being arrays takes too much time.
Is there any way I can set it where I loop through the x values and say specific y values have this z value for this x value. I am not sure if I explained this well enough let me know if I can clarify anything.

This is an example of how the plotly tutorial sets up heat maps but not related to my code. What I want to do is instead of having the Z values be represented in arrays for me to be able to say a specific x value and y value have this Z value since I have a large data set and because not all x values and y values will have a z value (that specific one will be 0). Right now how it works is notice how there are 3 z value arrays and 3 y value and each array of z values has 5 values one for each value. This wont work for me because I have 500+ x and y values.

```
public graph = {
    data: [
    {z: [[1, 20, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, -10, 20]],
    x: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    y: ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
    type: 'heatmap'}
    ],
    layout: {
      autosize: true,
      xaxis: {
      side: 'top'
      }
    }     
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> This wont work for me because I have 500+ x and y values.

Instead of creating the large array of your data, my suggestion is to use an object that maps your data to the heat map array.

In this way, the first part of the object contains the x-axis with the y-axis within it. The z-axis for each coordinate comes last. For example:

```
const myValues = {
  100: { // <- x-axis = 100
    100: 20, // <- y-axis = 100 with z-axis = 20 
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  }
}
```

After zero initializing the z-axis array with the `getBlank` function, use the `setMyValues` function to map the `myValues` object to full heat map.

See this snippet for an example and zoom into the 100 X 100 range to see the sample values.

```js
// your specific values
const myValues = {
  100: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  101: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  102: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  103: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  104: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  105: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  106: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  107: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  108: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  109: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  },
  110: {
    100: 20,
    101: 40,
    102: 60,
    103: 80,
    104: 100
  }
};
const z = getBlank(501, 501);
setMyValues();
const graph = {
  data: [{
    z: z,
    type: 'heatmap'
  }],
  layout: {
    autosize: true,
    xaxis: {
      side: 'top'
    }
  }
};

function setMyValues() {
  Object.keys(myValues).forEach(row => {
    Object.keys(myValues[row]).forEach(col => {
      z[row][col] = myValues[row][col];
    });
  });
}
// set blank heat map
function getBlank(xs, ys) {
  const z = [];
  const x = range(xs);
  const y = range(ys);
  x.forEach(row => {
    rowArray = [];
    y.forEach(col => {
      rowArray.push(0);
    });
    z.push(rowArray);
  });
  return z;
}

function range(size, startAt = 0) {
  return [...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);
}

TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.plot(TESTER, graph);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi can I do this if my X and Y values are strings and not ints? Also thanks for the help this seems like the most viable solution

Comment: My heat map has variable names as the Y and  constraint names as X then Z is the instances of each variable in each constraint. So I need the names displayed aswell.

Comment: Use `parseInt(“100”, 10)` to convert your strings.   I do not know how to label a heat map at this time.